# Matrix identity over a general field

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, block-matrices

This is a problem from Hoffman and Kunze: Let $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ be $n \times n$ matrices over an arbitrary field $F$ that commute with each other,
then the determinant of the the $2n \times 2n$ matrix
$
M = \begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{pmatrix}
$
is $\det(AD-BC)$.

I can see why this result is true if at least one of $A,B,C,$ or, $D$ is invertible. For example, if $A$ is invertible then from standard results on Schur complements, we have, $\det M = \det A \times \det ( D - BA^{-1}C ) = \det (A (D - BA^{-1}C) ) = \det (AD - BC).$

Using the above, one can see that this result is true when we are working over the field of complex or real numbers. For then we can always find a sequence $\epsilon_n \neq 0$ such that $\epsilon_n \to 0$ and $A_n = A+ \epsilon_n I $ is invertible. And since $A_n,B,C,$ and $D$ commute we get $\det \begin{pmatrix} A_n & B\\ C  & D \end{pmatrix} = \det (A_n D - BC)$ and let $n \to \infty.$ But this argument does not generalize to general fields.

How do we approach this problem for arbitrary fields?

Comment: One argument is as follows. As you have noted, this result is true when $F = \Bbb C$. However, both the expressions
$$
\det \pmatrix{A&B\\C&D}, \quad \det(AD - BC)
$$
are polynomials with integer entries over the entries of $A,B,C,D$. Because they have the same complex solutions, we can deduce that they are equal. Because these polynomials have integer coefficients and are equal, they must be equal over any field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same trick.    Take $A_{\lambda} = A + \lambda I$. Then we have

$$\det \left( \begin{matrix} A_{\lambda}& B \\C & D \end{matrix} \right)= \det (A_{\lambda} D - B C)$$
if $\det A_{\lambda} \ne 0$, or
$$\det A_{\lambda} \cdot \left( \det \left( \begin{matrix} A_{\lambda}& B \\C & D \end{matrix} \right)- \det (A_{\lambda} D - B C) \right)=0 $$

Now we have a polynomial in $\lambda$ that is $0$ for all values of $\lambda \in F$. That might not imply the polynomial being $0$ as yet, since $F$ could be finite. However, we can embed $F$ into a larger infinite field and work here. We conclude that the polynomial in $\lambda$ is $0$. Note that the polynomial  $\det A_{\lambda}$ as polynomial in $\lambda$ is $\ne 0$. It follows that the polynomial in $\lambda$ inside the bracket is $0$. Now we can give $\lambda$ the value $0$ and get the desired equality.

$\bf{Added:}$ Let's  prove: if matrices $A$, $B$ $C$, $D$ in $M_n(R)$, with $R$ a  commutative ring, and the matrices $A$, $B$ commute, then we have the equality above.

Assume first that $A$ is invertible, that is $\det A$ is invertible in $R$. Then we can do the reduction as in the OP and get the equality, using also $AB = BA$.

Now consider the general case. Consider the [ring of fraction](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RingofFractions.html) $R' \colon = S^{-1} R[\lambda]$ of the polynomial ring $R[\lambda]$, where $S = \{\det(\lambda I + A)^m\}_{m\ge 0} $. Here the matrix $\lambda I + A$ is invertible, and commutes with $B$. We conclude that we have the equality between determinants in the ring $R'$. This is equivalent to an equality

$$\det A_{\lambda}^m \cdot \left( \det \left( \begin{matrix} A_{\lambda}& B \\C & D \end{matrix} \right)- \det (A_{\lambda} D - B C) \right)=0 $$  in $R[\lambda]$ for some $m \ge 0$. Again, because the polynomial $\det A_{\lambda}^m$ in $\lambda $ is monic, we conclude that the RHS factor is $0$ in $R[\lambda]$. Now take $\lambda= 0$.

Comment: So if I understand your argument correctly, the polynomial $ P(\lambda) = \det A_{\lambda}⋅\left(\det\begin{pmatrix} A_{\lambda} & B \\ C & D \end{pmatrix} −\det(A_{\lambda} D−BC)\right)$ equals 0 when it is evaluated at every $\lambda$ in $F$. But that need not imply $P$ is the zero polynomial. But we can work in an infinite extension of $F$ and the same argument will show $P(\lambda)$ equals zero for all, so infinite , values of $\lambda$ in the extension, and so $P(\lambda) $ is the zero polynomial.

Comment: @Arin Chaudhuri: Yes, correct!